# Когда отсылаю запрос с формы поиска происходит зацикливание

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Есть метод поиска

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search"  method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search"   type="text">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

далее методом search я получаю из поста данные

```
public function search ()
{
    if (isset( $_POST['search'] )?$_POST['search']:null) {
        print_r ( $_POST );
        $text = self::protect ( $_POST['search'] );
        $search = new newsModel();
        $this->data['search'] = $search->search ( $text );
        $this->render ( 'search' );

    }

}
```

модель:

```
public function search($text)
{
   $text=$this->db->escape($text);
   $result=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE `title` LIKE '$text%'");
   return $result;
}
```

Class db:

```
 class DB
{
    private static $connection;
public static   function getInstance(){
    if (self::$connection===null){
        self::$connection=new \mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );
        self::$connection->query  ('SET NAMES UTF8');
        if (self::$connection->errno){
            die("Error while connect to MySql");
        }
    }
    return self::$connection;
}


private function __clone() { //запрещаем клонирование объекта модификатором private
}

protected function __wakeup(){

}

public function __construct ()
{
    $this->db=DB::getInstance ();
}

/**
 * @param $sql
 * @return array|bool|\mysqli_result
 */
public function query ($sql)
{
    $result = $this->db->query ( $sql );
    if (is_bool ( $result )) {
        return $result;
    }
    $data = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result )) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    if (!$data) {
        return false;
    }
    return $data;
}


/**
 * protect for sql injection
 * @param $value
 * @return string
 */
public function escape ($value)
{
    return $this->db->real_escape_string ( $value );
}
```

метод search вызывается в методе render

```
 protected function render($templateName)
{
    $data = $this->data;
    $message = $this->message;

    $data['menu']=self::getCat();
    self::search();
    ob_start();
    //динамический контент
    $render = SITE_DIR . DS . 'View' . DS . $this->name . DS . $templateName . '.php';
    if ($render) {
        include($render);
    }
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    include SITE_DIR . DS . 'View' . DS . 'Layout' . DS . $this->layout . '.php';
}
  public static function protect($text)
{
    $text = trim($text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    return $text;
}
```

Когда я посылаю запрос, отсылается много запросов и выдает ошибку "fatal error
Allowed memory size".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"he" это мой запрос.
Данные я могу получить, но они так само будут зацикленно выводиться, пока память не закончится.

Все остальное работает нормально только с поиском.

Comment: А функцию search какой метод вызывает?

Comment: мало данных. не ясно, например, тут: $search->search ( $text ), кто такая $text?

Comment: И зачем в search() ретёрн?

Comment: условие if (isset( $_POST['search'] )?$_POST['search']:null) избыточно

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin спасибо все исправил , метод search вызывается в методе render

Comment: $ text получаю с $text =  $_POST['search'] ;

Comment: return тоже убрал но без изменений

Comment: self::protect тоже покажите.

Comment: указал self::protect